# When login with other user it still picks previous user uuid from nowhere

Tags: swift, logout

I am working with some of my projects and the problem i am facing is when i login with user "A" and use the app for some time then i logout the user and then i login with another user "B" then in some of the screens where i have to show the user profile pic (Baseurl + profilepic name). It doesn't shows up, when i took a log of the profile pic url then i found that it still picking up the uuid of  old logged in user "A".

Note :- BaseUrl is made up with concatenation with uuid.

Here are the login and logout method classes and constant class which i am using to save the data on login response and nil the data on logout reponse

Login method if status is 1 :-

```
                        if(status == 1)
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                GAReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.DataDict, forKey:MaindataKey)
                                let Dict = self.mainDict[KData] as!  [String: AnyObject]
                                print("self.DataDict", self.DataDict)
                                let User_ID = Dict[KUuid]as! String
                                print(User_ID)
                                let HMACSECRETKEY = self.deviceToken + "+" + User_ID
                                kHMACKey = HMACSECRETKEY
                                let cipher:String = CryptoHelper.encrypt(input:HMACSECRETKEY)!;
                                print(HMACSECRETKEY)
                                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(cipher, forKey:HmacKey)
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
                                GAloginUserInfo.shared.saveUserInfo(dict: Dict )
                                let tabar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GAtHomeTabbarViewController") as! GAtHomeTabbarViewController
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabar, animated: true)

                            }
```

Logout method if status is 1 :-

```
                    if(status == 1)
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            GAReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()

                            defaults.removeObject(forKey: MaindataKey)
                            defaults.removeObject(forKey: HmacKey)
                            defaults.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
                            GAloginUserInfo.shared.removeUserInfo()


                            let login = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GALoginViewController") as! GALoginViewController
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(login, animated: true)

                        }
```

Constant class :-

```
import UIKit

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var kDeviceToken = String()
var kHMACKey = String()
let Headerkey = "header"
let KData = "data"
let KStatus = "status"
let KMessage = "message"
let MaindataKey = "MAINDATA"
let KUuid = "uuid"
let HmacKey = "HMACKEY"
let imageThumbBaseURL = "http://demodemodemo.ga/uploads/"+"\(GAloginUserInfo.shared.loginUserUuid!)"+"/video_thumbs/"
let videoFileBaseURL = "http://demodemodemo.ga/uploads/"+"\(GAloginUserInfo.shared.loginUserUuid!)"+"/video_files/"
let BaseURl = "http://demodemodemo.ga/index.php?api/"
let BaseURLProfilePic = "http://demodemodemo.ga/uploads/"+"\(GAloginUserInfo.shared.loginUserUuid!)"+"/profile_pic/"
```

Login user Shared class :-

```
import UIKit
class GAloginUserInfo: NSObject {
    var loginUserMobileNo : String?
    var loginUserId : String?
    var loginUserUuid : String?
    var loginUserCountry : String?
    var loginUserCountryCode : String?
    var loginUserEmail : String?
    var loginUserlatitude : String?
    var loginUserLongitude : String?
    var loginUserName : String?
    var loginUserQrcode : String?
    var loginUserProfilePic : String?
    var isverify : String?
    var loginPassword : String?
    var dateOfBirth: String?
    var earnedPoints:String?
    var loginUserGender:String?
    var loginUserFollowers:Int = 0

    static let shared = GAloginUserInfo()
    func saveUserInfo (dict : [String : AnyObject?] )  {


        if let loginUserMobileNo = dict["mobile"] as? String {
            self.loginUserMobileNo = loginUserMobileNo
        }
        if let loginUserId = dict["id"] as? String {
            self.loginUserId = loginUserId
        }
        if let loginUserUuid = dict["uuid"] as? String {
            self.loginUserUuid = loginUserUuid
            print(loginUserUuid)
        }
        if let loginUserCountry = dict["countryNameCode"] as? String {
            self.loginUserCountry = loginUserCountry
        }
        if let loginUserCountryCode = dict["country_code"] as? String {
            self.loginUserCountryCode = loginUserCountryCode
        }
        if let loginUserEmail = dict["email"] as? String {
            self.loginUserEmail = loginUserEmail
        }
        if let loginUserProfilePic = dict["profile_pic"] as? String {
            self.loginUserProfilePic = loginUserProfilePic
        }
        if let loginUserLongitude = dict["logitude"] as? String {
            self.loginUserLongitude = loginUserLongitude
        }
        if let loginUserName = dict["name"] as? String {
            self.loginUserName = loginUserName
        }
        if let loginUserQrcode = dict["qr_code"] as? String {
            self.loginUserQrcode = loginUserQrcode
        }
        if let Password = dict["password"] as? String{
            self.loginPassword = Password
        }
        if let dateOfBirth = dict["dob"] as? String{
            self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        }
        if let earnedPoints = dict["points"] as? String{
            let myDouble = Double(earnedPoints)
            let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", myDouble!)
            self.earnedPoints = doubleStr
        }
        if let loginUserGender = dict["gender"] as? String{
            self.loginUserGender = loginUserGender
        }
        if let loginUserFollowers = dict["followersCount"] as? Int{
            self.loginUserFollowers = loginUserFollowers
        }

    }

}
extension GAloginUserInfo {
    func removeUserInfo() {
        self.loginUserMobileNo = nil
        self.loginUserId = nil
        self.loginUserUuid = nil
        self.loginUserCountry = nil
        self.loginUserCountryCode = nil
        self.loginUserEmail = nil
        self.loginUserlatitude = nil
        self.loginUserLongitude = nil
        self.loginUserName = nil
        self.loginUserQrcode = nil
        self.loginUserProfilePic = nil
        self.isverify = nil
        self.loginPassword = nil
        self.dateOfBirth = nil
        self.earnedPoints = nil
        self.loginUserGender = nil
        self.loginUserFollowers = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you logOut UIKit will retain some values, to remove this,
When you logout you should clear all View controller so, your all UIKit data will remove and your problem is resolved. Put this code if your logout API status is 1.

```
let toViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KSLoginViewController") as! KSLoginViewController// Login view controller here
                                    let fromView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.view
                                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = toViewController
                                    
                                    let toView = toViewController.view
                                    toView?.addSubview(fromView!)
                                    
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.38, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {
                                        fromView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
                                    }, completion: { finished in
                                        fromView?.removeFromSuperview()
                                    })
```

After logout ,when you try to push another view controller  after logIn  use this code.

```
let teacher = studentStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KSStudentDashboardVC") as! KSStudentDashboardVC
                                        let aObjNavi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: teacher)
                                        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!
                                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = aObjNavi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem causes due to the threading. Move the non uikit classes operations from the main dispatch queue.

Login method if status is 1 :-

```
if(status == 1)
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.DataDict, forKey:MaindataKey)
        let Dict = self.mainDict[KData] as!  [String: AnyObject]
        print("self.DataDict", self.DataDict)
        let User_ID = Dict[KUuid]as! String
        print(User_ID)
        let HMACSECRETKEY = self.deviceToken + "+" + User_ID
        kHMACKey = HMACSECRETKEY
        let cipher:String = CryptoHelper.encrypt(input:HMACSECRETKEY)!;
        print(HMACSECRETKEY)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(cipher, forKey:HmacKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
        GAloginUserInfo.shared.saveUserInfo(dict: Dict )


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            GAReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()
            let tabar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GAtHomeTabbarViewController") as! GAtHomeTabbarViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabar, animated: true)

        }
    }
```

Logout method if status is 1 :-

```
if(status == 1)
    {
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: MaindataKey)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: HmacKey)
        defaults.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
        GAloginUserInfo.shared.removeUserInfo()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            GAReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()

            let login = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GALoginViewController") as! GALoginViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(login, animated: true)

        }
    }
```